# To redeploy an application on server restart in weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

I have installed WebLogic 10.3.6 in Production mode and I have deployed an EAR application in my Managed Server. How can I make sure that when I restart my Managed server then WebLogic will re-deploy my application once again?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can verify a deployment...

- Click the deployments link in the admin console, find your deployment, click it, and verify the path, staging mode, and targets are correct. You can also click on the monitoring tab to verify it is in the Active state.
- You can verify the same by opening the config.xml file in your /config directory. Look for the  tags

Once you've deployed, you don't need to worry about it disappearing when you restart. It will be there until you choose to remove it OR you delete the .ear file.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying, Actually my question is - I want my application to be re-deployed every time I restart my server. Can I do configuration like that?

Comment: If you set your deployment to nostage - it will automatically detect changes to the deployment and update JSPs/Servlets etc. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/deploy.html#1027044